# Hover effect on inline span goes away in between text gap

Tags: html, css

In the following setup, when hovering over the actual text, the hover effect fires, all good there. But the hover effect goes away when hovering over the gap in between the lines of text. I'd like the hover event to happens always even in the gaps. I know if I set it to display block, that will fix it. But in my particular case I need it to be inline.

```css
div {
  display: inline;
}

span {
  line-height: 40px;
}

span:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    long text, needs to be display inline. long text, needs to be display inline. long text, needs to be display inline. long text, needs to be display inline. long text, needs to be display inline. 
  <//span>
</div>
```

Comment: Add display: inline-block; to your span element's CSS.

Comment: i know that will fix it, but i need it to be just `inline`

Comment: What is the advantage of being inline instead of inline-block? If I know why you don't want to use inline-block, maybe I can help you approach it a different way.

Comment: because i have icons to the right of the text that will drop below if i use inline-block

Comment: Can you add that to your original question so this can be an [MCVE]?

Comment: What if you add padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px; to the span?

Comment: the span by default is inline

Answer (score 1):

try adding padding to the span, such as `padding: 15px 0px;` (top and bottom, not sides) to cover the gap between the lines. this should fix it

Answer (score 1):

Apply some padding top and bottom to span it cover gap between lines like "inline-block"